# How to tilt text in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to create a table that is going to have 21 columns. It does not look right on the website and goes off the side so you have to scroll across to see the end of the table.

I am wanting to tilt the titles of the columns because the values are only numbers which would all fit on the page. I have searched for this but can not seem to find it apart from one suggestion which is use images?

I know that it can be done in excel by rotating text but just do not know how to code it so it would do it in php/html.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [CSS `transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

Comment: Even better, I [googled "tilt text in a table html"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=tilt%20text%20in%20a%20table%20html) and [this was the top result.](http://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/) Crazy, right?

Comment: I googled the wrong thing, that's why i did not find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS to rotate the text.  Here is an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ta1fv823/2/)

HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr class="rotated">
    <td>The</td>
    <td>quick</td>
    <td>brown</td>
    <td>fox</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>The</td>
    <td>quick</td>
    <td>brown</td>
    <td>fox</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tr.rotated td {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```